# Pandas - count number of time windows in which specified values are present

Tags: python, pandas

I have comment data from a particular Subreddit for a little project I'm doing:

```
index    author  created_utc  ... body
0        user1   May 20 2018      "..."  
1        user1   Sep 28 2018      "..."  
2        user2   Apr 12 2017      "..."  
3        user7   Sep 22 2018      "..."
...      ...      ...               
32       user2   Jan 1 2018       "..."
```

(Note:
`created_utc` is an int in the format `1464737845`, but I've written it as a date in the example for clarity)

I would like to explore user engagement longevity. *Assuming I set my time window to be one month*, I would like to end up with a something along the lines of:

```
index    author  time_windows_present  
0        user1             2      
1        user2             2       
2        user7             1      
...      ...      ...
```

So far, I have gotten to the point of

```
comments_df.set_index('created_utc', inplace = True)
print(comments_df.resample('1M')['author'].count())
```

But that just gives me a monthly count for comments, and I have no clue how to take it further toward what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be the sort of thing that you're looking for:

```
def get_month_year(x):
    return str(x.month)+'_'+str(x.year)

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created'])
df['month_year'] = df['datetime'].apply(get_month_year)

#   author      created   datetime  month_year
# 0  user1  May 20 2018 2018-05-20     5_2018
# 1  user1  Sep 28 2018 2018-09-28     9_2018
# 2  user2  Apr 12 2017 2017-04-12     4_2017
# 3  user7  Sep 22 2018 2018-09-22     9_2018
# 4  user2   Jan 1 2018 2018-01-01     1_2018

df.groupby(by=['author','month_year']).count().reset_index()\
                                      .groupby('author')['created'].count()\
                                      .rename('time_windows_present').to_frame()

#         time_windows_present
# author                      
# user1                2
# user2                2
# user7                1
```